# How to upscale an image without affecting pixel aspect ratio?

Tags: image-processing, scaling

For example, if we upscale an image from 100 x 100 to 400 x 300 then we see the pixel stretch in the image which I want to eliminate.

The easiest way I could think is to crop the image to maintain the pixel aspect ratio i.e. upscaling to 300 x 300 or 400 x 400

Edit (Clarification): I want upscale an image without causing pixels to stretch, upsampling algorithms like nearest neighbor, bilinear interpolation, etc cause pixel stretching, especially when there is a change in aspect ratio e.g. from 1:1 to 16:9

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking a little bit more? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @A_A Please see the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popular cheap methods are:

- Letterboxing
  [image]
- Cropping
  [image]
- A combined method: cropping, overlapped by the letterboxed image
  [image]

The combined method works surprisingly well in videos, and people are quite accustomed to viewing such videos.

Photoshop and others also have smart content-aware scaling/resizing algorithms that re-organize or generate image content to the new image size. I don't have PhotoShop to demonstrate it with, but here is [a video from Adobe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUiV_CC2KCQ).